# Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture Duplicate Class

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't build my project, with every new dependency that I try to add I get a fist full of new errors. 
I tried migrating my project using the IDE to androidx libraries, but that didn't solve anything.

Right now I have these libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    compile 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
    compile 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation('com.github.evgenyneu:js-evaluator-for-android:v4.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'

}
```

And I get this error:
Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

Have no idea how to properly set everything up, it's driving me crazy.

Edit
Logs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar
Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\Liudas\AndroidStudioProjects\Bakalaurinis40\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar
Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:65)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:90)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add the following code snippet to your project inside `gradle.properties`.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Then `Clean` and finally `Build` the project. It should work. If you are still getting errors, copy and paste the logs here.

**Edit**:
Add the following to your `build.gradle` in app module.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

The error is usually caused by some dependecies that implements Google's  guava library.

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Comment: That helped solve that problem, but now it gives me:
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout

Comment: Change every occurrence of your `...ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` including the `import ...ConstraintLayout` . That should work.

Comment: Moreover you might be getting constant build fails. This was because you have just migrated to `androidx...`. To fix this issues, go to the affected files in your log and replace the dependencies in question with the ones here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: is this solution excluding listenablefuture safe? What it could affect?